# Has anyone applied for Schengen Visa from a country where they've been in for less than 3 months?

Tags: visas, uk, schengen

I'm on exchange in the UK for 9 months and have only lived here for a month right now. I was planning to travel around Europe during Christmas. (I have a Chinese passport and have lived in Canada for 5 years before this and am going back to Canada after the exchange term if that's relevant)

I understand they require the applicant to be in the UK for at least 3 months but that would be a bit late for Christmas break.

According to [this page](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/apply-from-uk/),

> To apply for a Schengen visa from the UK you must be a UK resident for at least three months. If this condition is not fulfilled, the Consulate of your country of preference will hardly take the application into consideration.

It only says "hardly considered" but didn't say it'll definitely be rejected. I think I have pretty good reasons to apply from the UK but not sure if it's worth a try.

So I was wondering if anyone has ever got a Schengen visa from a country where you've lived in for less than 3 months or has been in a similar situation?

Comment: That's not an official Schengen website....

Comment: That schengenvisainfo site is wrong. You can apply if you are resident in the country and there is no minimum time. See the linked Q&A for the official references.

Comment: The nonsensical use of the word "hardly" is a clue that the website shouldn't be taken as authoritative.